# a program to populate a stack ( own stack class) with random numbers at random interval

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

a program to populate a stack (own stack class) with random numbers at random interval. The inserted item should be added to a variable called sum.

thread keeps an eye on the stack and when an item is available modifies the total

I got my stack created

```
public int capacity { get; set; }
    int[] stack;
    int top = 0;

public int push(int element)
    {
        if (top == capacity - 1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            top = top + 1;
            stack[top] = element;

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

got confused on two things first for set intervals, I know I am wrong at the timer but where ???

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(rand.Next(1000, 5000));

        t.Elapsed += (s,r) => { insertIntoStack(); };
        t.Enabled = true;
        t.Start();

    }

public void insertIntoStack()
    {
        textBox1.Text = stack1.getsum().ToString();
        int number = stack1.generateRandomNumber();
        textBox2.Text = number.ToString();
        stack1.push(number);
        textBox3.Text = stack1.getsum().ToString();

    }


public int generateRandomNumber()
    {
        int number = 0;
        System.Random rand = new Random();
        number = rand.Next(1, 99);

        return number;
    }

    public void doSum()
    {
        sum += stack[top];
    }
```

and second one for thread keeps an eye on the stack and when an item is available modifies the total can anyone help, am totally new to c#

Comment: Every time you click the button you create a new timer with a new elapsed event handler. Surely that can't be what you want?

Comment: what I want is single click of button and the timer will create new random time and after this time generate random number which added to sum and then again continue to create random time and generate random number and so on until I add a condition

Answer (score 0):

It's probably something freezing within your `insertIntoStack()` function - you have not provided all the code needed to debug that (I don't know how `generateRandomNumber()` or `getSum()` works).

You should look into using [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) or [`Stack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.stack?view=netframework-4.7.2), rather than `int[]`, if you want to dynamically push onto it.

Comment: have to use own created stack , so used int[ ]

Comment: @Ajay, you should use the tools .NET and C# provide you. If you wanted help with `List<T>`, you would not have needed to provide all the code you wrote too.